# How to access the type of a property in a nested type below an indexer?

Tags: typescript

Given:

```
interface Example {
    items: {
        [k: string]: {
            name: string;
            value: {
                subName: {
                    subValue: string;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

It's possible to create a type for `items` with a lookup type:

`type Items = Example['items'];`

But what if I want to get the type below the indexer?

`type SubItems = Example['items']['']['value'];`

The above won't work. Is there a way to access the type of the `value` object?

Comment: On TS playground I get the correct type for the expression you say won't work. However you should specify `string` instead of `''`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
type SubItems = Example["items"][string]["value"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it hierarchically. Please look at this:

```
interface Example {
    items: {
        [k: string]: {
            name: string;
            value: {
                subName: {
                    subValue: string;
                };
            };
        };
    };
}

var example = {
  items:{
    'item':{
      name:'1',
      value:{
        subName:{
          subValue:'2'
        }
      }
    }
    } 
} as Example

console.log(example['items']['item']['value']['subName']['subValue']); //2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around. Specify your types explicitly:

```
interface ItemValue {
    subName: { subValue: string }
}

interface Item {
    name: string;
    value: ItemValue;
}

interface Example {
    items: {
        [k: string]: Item
    }
}
```